# AEM and SOLR integration

Tags: java, solr, aem

I have done Solr and AEM integration using the below link and am not able to index the html content from AEM into SOLR.

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/aem_solr.html.

I get the below issue when I try to index content from AEM to Solr.

> Cannot serve request to /bin/solr/push/pages in
>   com.adobe.aem.core.servlets.IndexContentToSolr

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
     at com.adobe.aem.core.utils.SolrUtils.solrDate(SolrUtils.java:48).
```

Comment: Would you please give more of the stack trace of the NullPointerException? I assume that you are trying to handle a date in your 'IndexContentToSolr Servlet' that is null, which you do not check.

Comment: Check your date formats for the document or custom properties. By default solr can handle the UTC format but error suggests that you may be passing something else

Comment: public static String solrDate(Calendar cal) {
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
  return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + "Z";

Comment: ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");I have this in SolrUtils.java class

Comment: @cheffeInternal Server Error

Cannot serve request to /bin/solr/push/pages in com.adobe.aem.core.servlets.IndexContentToSolr

Exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.adobe.aem.core.utils.SolrUtils.solrDate(SolrUtils.java:48)
 at com.adobe.aem.core.impl.SolrSearchServiceImpl.createPageMetadataObject(SolrSearchServiceImpl.java:140)

Comment: I had indexed "xyz" content in IST timings.I was trying to index the same content "xyz" after location change in PST timings and had an issue.In PST timings I indexed a new content and am able to do it without issues.I am able to reindex the same content in PST timings now.Was getting date time format issue so I think this makes sense.

Comment: Not directly an answer but I also tried to get the example running and decided to use the Jackrabbit Features for Solr which are quite fine and don't need any additonal code for indexing. I documented the complete required steps and a sample application (available on github) here: https://www.dev-eth0.de/blog/2017/02/27/solr-aem.html